# URL only resolving with TOR Browser otherwise error ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: url, github, dns, cloudflare

I've the following situation. I made a SPA with React/Redux and deployed it with gh-pages to github. In the package.json the homepage is `https://www.url.com`. The DNS on the domain provider (Uniregistry) points to my cloudflare instance. On cloudflare I have 4x A-records pointing to the IP for github. And one CNAME with `wwww`which resolves to `iepur1lla.github.io`.

When I try to access the URL via Chrome I get `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`, though when I try to access the URL via TOR browser it works perfectly fine, redirect and SSL certificate, everything.

At first I researched on Stackoverflow, what could cause this issue, and I checked the DNS propagation for my country. And it points to Cloudflare, and my github URL points to the IPs which are as A records in cloudflare.

I really could use an advice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved. After investigating with the `dig` and `nslookup` commands, I found out that in some cases the default DNS from Uniregistry which has been updated to Cloudflare DNS, was still resolving. I went to `uniregistry` and `purged my DNS servers` and `put the same cloudflare DNS in` and after waiting the TTL time it resolved fine. Yay!